# MySQL performance on Mac vs Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, mac-os-x

I know that MySQL is tested more on Linux (Oracle has it's own linux distribution and you canot have LAMP wit MySQL (meaning MySQL has always focused more on Linux)

My intuition says that MySQL has a better performance on Linux than on any other OS (including FreeBSD based MacOS). But I don't have facts to back it up.

Can you point me to any references  which can help me determine whether moving MySQL from MacOS to Linux would give a performance boost= What has been your own experience?

I guess the only other way is to measure difference KPIs on both Linux and MacOS and then try to compare them. But I am trying to put more justifications for purchase of Linux ready hardware and cannot compare the two at the moment.

Comment: For dev/test or production use? Hardly anybody uses Mac OS X Server in production.

Comment: we are the exception :). Macs every where Dev/Test/Production.

Comment: I also ran on Mac XServes until recently (last 8 months). Anecdotal, but I didn't notice any performance increase that wasn't tied to hardware specs (moved to a clearly better server). Not part of your question, but the only issue I ran into in migration was [table case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names). Only pointing it out to help avoid mishaps!

Comment: @DTest yeah table case sensitivity is a problem that we had to solve in application (make sure every thing was in in CAPS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [PDF](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/files/presentations/UC2004-OS-and-Hardware.pdf), there's no clear winner when we compare MySql performance between different Kernel.

Since all databases are different, you will have to do benchmark to be sure. I think the hardware spec will affect the performance more than the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my opinion...

I've been working same database & routines on Debian 8 Database Virtual Server 32 GB RAM 8cpu Xenon vs MAC Maverics 8 GB RAM 4 cpu corei7 and MAC's performance is superior over 50 times on speed measures.

Then in order to use the same hardware settings I decided repeat the test Running debian 8 on my MAC versus  MAC's Maverics. Again OSX is better.

The answer comes form the multicore response betwwen operatings systems. Debian Mysql trends to avoid multi-core while there is enought free memory reserving resources for other users. OSX performs distribution  as soon as the process start consumming memory resources (of course Maverics is oriented  on single user).